# How to (get or print) the value of my button on tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How can I get the value/text also print of my button A. B. C.? What should the right code to get that value.. thanks a lot!

Here is my sample code.. I'm starting to study the tkinter for my personal project and I want to create my own Multiple Choice Quiz. I already search the net but cant find the answer to my question :( Your help really appreciated!

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("MultipleChoice")
root.geometry("500x500")

title = tk.Label(text="Multiple Choice Quiz")
title.place(x=250, y=10, anchor="center")
title.pack()

def ff():
    tk.Label(root, text= "").pack()

A = tk.Button(root, text="A", command = ff)
A.pack()
B = tk.Button(root, text="B", command = ff)
B.pack()
C = tk.Button(root, text="C", command = ff)
C.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want to get the text of button A, you can use `A.cget('text')` or `A['text']`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for. This prints the corresponding buttons text into the console window:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.title("MultipleChoice")
root.geometry("500x500")

title = tk.Label(text="Multiple Choice Quiz")
title.place(x=250, y=10, anchor="center")
title.pack()

def ff(input):
    print(input)

A = tk.Button(root, text="A", command = lambda: ff(A['text']))
A.pack()
B = tk.Button(root, text="B", command = lambda: ff(B['text']))
B.pack()
C = tk.Button(root, text="C", command = lambda: ff(C['text']))
C.pack()

root.mainloop()
```